# Why does this while loop never evaluate to true?

Tags: c++, cin

If the file has a list of coordinates and a character:

```
(1,2,3,A)
// blah blah
(10,20,30,B)
(11,22,33,C)
```

the expression in the `while` loop never evaluates to true, Why is this?

```
string str = "";
char aa, cc, ee, gg, hh, ii;
int bb, dd, ff;
while(cin >> aa >> bb >> cc >> dd >> ee >> ff >> gg >> hh >> ii ||
      cin >> str) {
    if(str != "") {
        cout << str << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << aa << " " << bb << " " << cc << " " << dd << " " << ee << " " <<  ff << " " << gg << " " << hh << " " << ii << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a `std::vector`, please.

Comment: try to avoid telling us that things "do not work", instead, describe the specific errors/incorrect output that you get.  It makes it easier for us to diagnose the problem

Comment: Sorry! I just edited it. For some reason, my while loop never evaluates to true.

Answer (score 3):

Once you stream has gone into fail-state, i.e., `std::ios_base::failbit` is set, the stream won't do anything until the stream got cleared. That is, if your first input failed, the second input will fail, too. What would work is spinning things around: first read the string and then using a string stream to see if it decodes into the constituents.